# PHP How to convert array json string to array?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, associative-array

How to convert JSON array string to array
Example - this is array json string -

```
$params = [{"143":"166"},{"93":"49"}];
```

when using json_decode

```
$options1 = json_decode($params, true);
```

but it returns

```
[super_attribute1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [143] => 166
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [93] => 49
                )

        )
```

but I need how can we convert in this format ?

```
super_attribute] => Array
        (
            [143] => 163
            [93] => 49
        )
```

Comment: The example you've shown does not correspond to the result you're getting.

Comment: `super_attribute] => Array` does not look like a valid result - please share more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nester foreach can solve this for you

```
<?php

$data = [
    [ 143=>166 ],
    [ 93=>49 ]
];

$return = [];
foreach ($data as $d)
{
    foreach ($d as $k=>$v) $return[$k] = $v;
    unset($v);
} unset($d);

var_dump($return); // array(2) { [143]=> int(166) [93]=> int(49) }
```

Answer (score 0):

just use a loop or a map to convert the result

```
function customJsonDecode($jsonString) {
    $decode = json_decode($jsonString, true);
    $result = [];
    foreach($decode as $item) $result = array_merge($result, array_pop($item));
    return $result;
}
```